# Error: could not open 'C:\Java\jre8\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

Tags: java

I downloaded this  "https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html#license-lightbox" Java JDK and installed it.

But when I go to the command prompt to check the version, it says

> ```
> Error: could not open 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
> ```

Can someone solve my problem?

[image]

Comment: follow this https://www.java67.com/2015/10/error-could-not-open-java-jmv-cfg-lib-eclipse.html

Answer (score 5):

Simply uninstall the java version from the control panel and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue of `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg` do the following steps and re-run the cmd :

1) Go to `C:\Windows\System32`

2) Search for Java in that folder

3) Remove `java.exe`, `javaws.exe` and `javaw.exe` from this folder

4) Open command prompt.

5) Type `Java` it should work.

Comment: my system does not contain java.exe, javaws.exe, javaw.exe file in the above reffered folder "C:\Windows\System32".my aim to learn java has been stopped.

Comment: @SANJEEVKUMAR another reason may be that file corruption or file may be deleted. You should download and re-install it again. That might help.Let me know if this resolve the issue.

Comment: yeah!  I have   solved the problem with your help thank u @bakdoor

Comment: @SANJEEVKUMAR Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

->Firstly uninstall Java(any version) here it is 1.8

->Then Goto->environment variable-> Check the java path which is appended[in my case a default java was installed] i had to remove it

->Now install java 1.8

->then set the java path for the "PATH" variable = %JAVA_HOME%\bin
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

->Open Command prompt and give java -version to verify the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Only Windows OS problem. Remove from system32 you kept trash in other locations where java has installed (updates example). Just reinstall java will help. Situation to gain that error may be different (my situation when java location was different than java update I installed long ago). Add/remove java solved problem.